# Suppose $0 < r < 1$. Show that $\sum_{k=q+1}^p r^k \leq \frac{r^{q+1}}{1-r}$ if $p > q$.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that $\sum_{k=q+1}^p r^k \leq \frac{r^{q+1}}{1-r}$ for any $p > q$, if $0 < r < 1$, but I'm having trouble getting equality. Here is what I did:

Recall that: $\sum_{k=0}^p r^k = \frac{1 - r^{p+1}}{1 - r}$, so it follows that $\sum_{k=q+1}^p r^k = \sum_{k=0}^p r^k - \sum_{k=0}^q r^k = \frac{1 - r^{p+1}}{1 - r} - \frac{1 - r^{q+1}}{1 - r} = \frac{r^{q+1}-r^{p+1}}{1-r} = \frac{r^{q+1}(1-r^{p-q})}{1-r}$.

Since $0 < r < 1$ we get $0 < 1-r^{p-q} < 1$ and $0 < \frac{r^{q+1}}{1-r}(1-r^{p-q}) < \frac{r^{q+1}}{1-r}$.

Therefore $\sum_{k=q+1}^p r^k < \frac{r^{q+1}}{1-r}$.

My question is how do I get equality $(\leq)$? Is there something I'm missing that allows me to say its less than or equal to?

Comment: I haven't looked that closely to your math, but it seems like you know what you are doing.  Anyway, if you are asked to prove that $A \leq B$, and (instead), you prove that $A < B$, **you are done**.  That is, you proved a stronger statement.

Comment: ooo I'm fancy. I'll have to double-check that with my prof.

Comment: So I was asked to prove "less than OR equal to". I proved "less than" and that is sufficient, yes?

Comment: Yes, because $3 < 4$, it follows that $3 \leq 4.$

Answer (score 1):

A little simpler.

$\begin{array}\\
s(r, p, q)
&=\sum_{k=q+1}^p r^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{p-q-1} r^{k+q+1}\\
&=r^{q+1}\sum_{k=0}^{p-q-1} r^{k}\\
&=r^{q+1}\dfrac{1-r^{p-q}}{1-r}\\
&\lt\dfrac{r^{q+1}}{1-r}
\quad\text{since } 0 < r < 1 \text{ and } p > q\\
\end{array}
$